# Flushing completely left in the middle of a list (such as enumerate)

Tags: enumerate

```
\begin{enumerate}
 \item Item 1
 \begin{enumerate}
    \item Subitem 1
    I need this line to be flushed completely to the left margin of the PAGE
    \item Subitem 2
  \end{enumerate}
 \item Item 2
\end{enumerate}
```

Please consider the code above. Naturally subitems 1 and 2 are at the second level of the list and so are indented. Suppose I want to add a line (between Subitem 1 and Subitem 2) that needs to be flushed left with the left margin of the page (ignoring all the indentations of the list). How can this be done please?

Answer (score 5):

Please always post *complete* documents not just fragments.

You can copy the definition of `quote` but with a negative indent:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{wide}
               {\list{}{\leftmargin-\@totalleftmargin\rightmargin0pt}%
                \item\relax}
               {\endlist}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{enumerate}
 \item Item 1
 \begin{enumerate}
    \item Subitem 1
\begin{wide}
    I need this line to be flushed completely to the left margin of the PAGE
\end{wide}
    \item Subitem 2
  \end{enumerate}
 \item Item 2
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution is very robust indeed. It does not depend on the enumerate spacings themselves. I can call it from wherever I need. Brilliant.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}
 \item Item 1
 \begin{enumerate}
    \item Subitem 1\par
    \hspace*{\dimexpr-\leftmargini-\leftmarginii}I need this line to be flushed completely to the left margin of the PAGE 
    \item Subitem 2
  \end{enumerate}
 \item Item 2
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. However I prefer the first solution because it is more general and can be used from any level of the enumerate that I need .