# Interrupting Nested Lists in LaTeX

Tags: lists, nesting

How do I interrupt and resume nested lists at any level in LaTeX?  Something like

```
I. Item Level 1
    A. Item Level 2
        1. Item Level 3
comment at level 1
        2. Item Level 3
    B. Item Level 2
        1. Item Level 3
    comment at level 2
comment at level 1
        2. Item Level 3
II. Item Level 1
```

(A similar question was asked and answered for non-nested lists: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348194/how-to-interrupt-resume-a-list-in-latex)

Comment: its basically the exact same question.

Comment: One solution can be seen in the answer to this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113840/flushing-completely-left-in-the-middle-of-a-list-such-as-enumerate.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do but I think you should consider if you really want to do this. Should the reader be able to figure out which level-1 item the comment belongs to? I'd consider this highly inconvenient. Also it would require the reader should backtrack to the inner list level. I'd advise you to change the presentation. If you _really_ need to make a comment about a level 1 item, perhaps you could consider using a footnote.

Answer (score 3):

To continue the innermost list you can use an empty item in the second level to avoid error. Continuing the enumeration in the inner list does not seem to work, so that must be done manually.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\newcounter{tempcounter}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Item Level 1
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Item Level 2
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Item level 3
            \setcounter{tempcounter}{\value{enumiii}}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
    \item[] Comment at level 1
    \begin{enumerate}[resume]
        \item[]
        \begin{enumerate}
            \setcounter{enumiii}{\value{tempcounter}}
            \item Item Level 3
        \end{enumerate}
        \item etc.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: List]

Note that there is no clear way to align the comment with the label of the first-level list, since the labels are right-aligned.